# Excel- Given a start and end date, create an array of the dates between the two

Tags: excel

I have Start Date and end date for some IDs,

**Data Set 1**

```
ID          Trans_Date     Action
1234567890  01-Jan-2012    Active
1234567890  05-Jan-2012    Dc
1234567890  06-Jan-2012    Active
1234567890  12-Jan-2012     Dc
1234567890  15-Jan-2012    Active
```

I need to expand the set as below,

**Required data set,**

```
ID          Trans_Date  Action
1234567890  01-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  02-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  03-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  04-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  05-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  06-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  07-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  08-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  09-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  10-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  11-Jan-12   Active
1234567890  12-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  13-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  14-Jan-12   DC
1234567890  15-Jan-12   Active
```

Currently I’m doing manual labor work, is there and formula or VBA code for that?

Please refer the question asked on **'SO'** as

*Given a start and end date, create an array of the dates between the two.*

I need the same on excel.

Comment: Should the last dates in the first list be 12-Jan-2012 and 15-Jan-2012? Also do you definitely want 13-Jan-12 and 14-Jan-12 to be filled in as DC, not a gap between 12-Jan-12 and 15-Jan-12?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Correcting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could develop the list in two spare columns (e.g. D and E) using formulae. If your first list is in columns A-C:-

(1) Copy the first date (C2) into D2

(2) Put this formula in D3 and pull down:-

```
=IF(D2>=MAX(B$2:B$6),"",D2+1)
```

(3) Put this formula in E2 and pull down:-

```
=IF(D2="","",INDEX(C$2:C$6,MATCH(D2,B$2:B$6,1)))
```

This could be extended for different ID numbers:-

(1) Copy the first ID number into D2

(2) Put this formula in D3

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D2,D2)<(MAX(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))-MIN(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))+1),
   D2,
   INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D2, $A$2:$A$20), 0)))
```

(3) Put this formula in E2:-

```
=MIN(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20))+COUNTIF(D$1:D1,D2)
```

(4) Put this formula in F2:-

```
=INDEX(C$2:C$20,MATCH(E2,IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20),1))
```

All these are array formulae and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

But could be slow if applied to many rows of data.

Comment: Thanks you sir,  but the original data contains more than 20000 entries. It will be very difficult to arrange. Also the solution is throwing an error. I'll try it again and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I can see that it will be more complicated if you have a lot of different ID's as well. Will give it some more thought, but you might need a VBA solution in the end.

Comment: Thank you sir, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Thank You Sir, Million Thanks